# Publishing a topic/message in a callback member function

Tags: ros, callback, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I attempt to publish a topic/messages in a callback member function (refer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3204/subscription-a-topic-from-another-package) in the answers section), but, it doesn't work. The code is compiled without any complaints, however, when I issue a command to see the published message, say, *ros echo -c /topic*, it shows nothing there.

Is it not doable publishing it in the callback member function? Are there any alternatives to that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12353/publishing-a-topic/message-in-a-callback-member-function/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-12-15**:
Are you sure your callback is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is doable.

Other than that, you will need to give more information.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2